# Find nonempty lines without string, in N++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to use Notepad++ Regex to find all lines that are (1) not empty and (2) do *not* contain the string ": ", prefixing only them with "{Undelimited}". The string will never occur at the start or end of the line.

So if the input (with an empty line represented as "[Empty Line]") is:

> Item #: SCP-173
>
> [Empty Line]
>
> Object is animate and extremely hostile.
>
> One:Two:Three

The output is:

> Item #: SCP-173
>
> [Empty Line]
>
> {Undelimited}Object is animate and extremely hostile.
>
> {Undelimited}One:Two:Three

Every solution I can find on Stack Overflow uses negative lookaheads and matches empty lines.

Comment: Find `(?m)^(?=.*\S)(?!.*: )` , Replace `{Undelimited}`

Comment: @sln no need for the multiline modifier, Notepad++ uses it per default.

Comment: Just for brevity. It does accept inline modifiers ?

Comment: Yes, it does - it's just not needed in this case.

Comment: I would always choose to use inline modifiers if accepted, in place of compile options. For instance if I take off modifiers within a scoped section, I would not pollute the action with any pretensed state.

Comment: That one also matches empty lines. ^(?!.*: ).+$ or ^(?!.+: ).+$ (below) seems to work fine.

Comment: Yeah, `pretensed state` or to just right the ship to the initial state. Avoids any user error and is cut'n paste portable.

Comment: Note that empty lines are often confused with blank lines, invisible whitespace.

Comment: It contains a colon, not a colon immediately followed by a space. The latter is the delimiter string.

Comment: If the answers below work, please consider accepting the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

No empty lines, i.e. not whitespaced lines

Find `(?m)^(?=.*\S)(?!.*: )` , Replace `{Undelimited}`